# Volume integral on analytic manifolds

Tags: integration, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

On smooth Riemannian manifolds, you can always find a smooth partition of unity:
$$\{\varphi_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\mathfrak{A}},\qquad \sum_{\alpha\in\mathfrak{A}}\varphi_\alpha=1$$
and only finitely many $\varphi_\alpha$ are non-zero in any region. If you calculate a local $n$-form from orthonormal coordinates:
$$dx^1\land dx^2\land\cdots\land dx^n$$
You can use this to define a volume form $d$vol over your Riemannian manifold.

How is this done for analytic or Hermitian manifolds? Since, in this case, you cannot have a non-zero function with compact support, so a partition of unity is impossible. I'm sure there are results on this but I am struggling to find any myself. Any help/links would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: On an complex manifold with an hermitian form, if it is given by analytic functions then it is a Kahler manifold. You can define the same $C^\infty_c$ partitions of unity and local volume form but it won't be given by analytic functions.

Comment: Does that mean a volume form on a real analytic manifold cannot be analytic?

Comment: What do you get with $\Bbb{R}^2$ or $\Bbb{R}^2/\Bbb{Z}^2$ ?